# MPEG-DASH trick modes Representation

Tags: mpeg-dash, representation, fast-forward

DASH-IF document explains that in order to support trick mode, separate Representations should be added in the MPD ([source](https://dashif.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/DASH-IF-IOP-v4.2-clean.htm#_Toc511040730))

The document also indicates that the content owner should

> signal the playout capabilities with the attribute @maxPlayoutRate for each Representation in order to indicate the accelerated playout that is enabled by the signaled codec profile and level.

Could anyone please provide an example of an adaptation set, showing the information that should be included in the Representations for trick mode support. Also, can we have different @maxPlayoutRate values for different Levels of media streams. If yes, how can we signal this information using MPD.

Answer (score 1):

DASH-IF makes a number of examples manifests containing trick mode Adaptation Sets available at http://testassets.dashif.org/#feature/details/586fb3879ae9045678eab58b (note the first time you navigate to this site you may have to click through a disclaimer and will be redirected to the wrong place).